# Copy Function Pointer to Block of Memory in C

Tags: c, stack, pthreads, posix, function-pointers

I am working on implementing a threading library using the pthreads API.  One of the things I need to do is allocate a stack of size 32767 bytes and then put the function pointer to pthread_exit at the top of the stack, and decrement the stack pointer to be below that function pointer.

The code I have come up with is as follows:

```c
    void *stackPointer = malloc(32767);
    stackPointer += 32767;
    stackPointer -= sizeof(&pthread_exit);
    stackPointer = memcpy(stackPointer, pthread_exit, sizeof(&pthread_exit));
```

From what I can tell the function pointer is not properly placed in the memory by using the memcpy function in this way.  Is there another way I should be going about this (or function I should be using)?

Edit:
Fixed code to have stack pointer at the top from the start

Comment: Size odd number. I think that you need to rethink it. And you need to learn how the stack works. Answering your question memory is 100% fine.

Comment: This is so wrong in so many ways. First of all, you're incrementing by `sizeof(void (*stackPointer)(void))` **squared** bytes. Second, as you state, stack grows *down* on your architecture so you should be starting from *top* and be *decrementing*, third, `32767` looks very odd for the pointer, fourth you must not modify the malloc-returned pointer or else how are you going to free the memory, and fourth are you sure the stack pointer position would be correct even then...

Comment: `memcpy` copies the pointed-to data, not the pointer itself, but I think it's the latter that you actually want to write.

Comment: Are you sure you want the the stack pointer to point *below* the top element, as opposed to *at* it?  If so, then how many bytes below, 1?  For a downward-growing stack, my first guess would be that the stack pointer would point at the top element, so that when you want to push a value, you decrement the pointer by the size of that value to find the right address (and then don't need to adjust it again after writing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of suspicious things with the code presented.  Among these are

- it is non-conforming to do pointer arithmetic with pointers of type `void *`;
- you appear to be discarding the only pointer to a dynamically-allocated block, making it tricky, if possible at all, to deallocate the block later; and
- depending on how you intend to use it, it may be an issue that you do not ensure correct alignment of the value you are pushing on the stack.

But those are comparatively small: some compilers do what you appear to want with void-pointer arithmetic, you may be able to recompute the pointer needed to deallocate the block, and maybe alignment isn't a concern for your purposes.

However,

> From what I can tell the function pointer is not properly placed in the memory by using the memcpy function in this way.

No, it definitely isn't.  The `memcpy()` function copies *the data pointed to* by the source pointer to the location indicated by the destination pointer.  You want to write the pointer itself, which is another matter altogether.

> Is there another way I should be going about this (or function I should be using)?

You could store the pointer in a variable and then copy it from there:

```
#define STACK_SIZE 32767

void (*pte)(void *) = pthread_exit;

void *stackLimit = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
void *stackBottom = stackLimit + STACK_SIZE;
void *stackPointer = (char *) stackBottom - sizeof(pte);

memcpy(stackPointer, pte, sizeof(pte));
```

Or if unaligned access were not an issue (or if a stack size a little more or less than 32767 were ok) then you could do it more simply with a plain assignment:

```
void *stackLimit = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
void *stackBottom = stackLimit + STACK_SIZE;
typedef void (*pte_type)(void *);

((pte_type) stackBottom)[-1] = pthread_exit;
void *stackPointer = (pte_type) stackBottom - 1;
```

The typedef is for clarity and reading ease.  Equivalent code could be written without.

Note that expressions of function type, such as `pthread_exit` is when the declaration of that function is in scope, are automatically converted to function pointers. You don't need to use the `&` operator on them, though it's harmless to do so.